# Can someone explain to me this code, it is in JavaScript and I am trying to understand how observable are created

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I don't really understand what is happening in this code. 
Are we passing a function and getting an object, and then creating a new class ? 
Thank you in advance
and how is .subscribe({}) is aware of the next value.
I would appreciate if someone explains how to debug it

```
function Observable(subscribe) {
  this.subscribe = subscribe;
}
const one$ = new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.complete();
});

one$.subscribe({
  next: value => console.log(value), // 1
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are we passing a function

Yes

> and getting an object

Yes. `new` creates an instance of a class, which is an object.

> and then creating a new class ?

No.

The function declaration creates a class:

> ```
> function Observable(subscribe) {
>   this.subscribe = subscribe;
> }
> ```

Invoking it with `new` creates an instance of that class:

> ```
> const one$ = new Observable(value);
> ```

---

> how is .subscribe({}) is aware of the next value.

Because you pass it explicitly:

> ```
> observer.next(1);
> ```

Comment: so is this a function or what `next(1)`

Comment: @JSLover — `next` is a function. You defined it here: ```{
  next: value => console.log(value), // 1
}```

Comment: @JSLover `next` is a function defined through the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: what about this `observer.next(1);`

Comment: @JSLover — What about it?

Comment: I don't understand that syntax, does that mean observer will have a property of next ?

Comment: @JSLover — Yes, and the vlaue is a function.

Comment: why can't we do something like this 
```
let y = {}
undefined
y.x(1)
VM284:1 Uncaught TypeError: y.x is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

Comment: @JSLover — Because you didn't define x

Comment: and in here observer => {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.complete();
} we are saying that it takes a function and then return an object?

Comment: @JSLover — That bit of code doesn't. That is a function, which accepts an object as an argument, then calls two methods on it, and returns nothing.